# Excel vlookup and adding time

Tags: excel, function, vlookup

I have some date/time cells in Excel and I would like to add a certain amount of time onto them (savinng the new value in another cell). Here is how it would look:

Main sheet:

[image]

Sheet3:

[image]

So in the main sheet, for column E I want to match the main's column D with column B in Sheet3 and based on that add column C (Sheet3) to the date in column C (main sheet) then store the new date in main's column E.

Column C (sheet3) represents the amount of hours to be added.

How to go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this formula in column E of your main sheet:

```
=C1+VLOOKUP(D1,Sheet3!$B$1:$C$9,2,FALSE)
```

Assuming you want to add days. If you want to add seconds or hours, you'll need to adjust the time in column C of Sheet 3.

Comment: Thanks. Those numbers are hours, so 48 would be 2 days. So how to change the format of 48, 96? Because 04:00:00 works fine but 48:00:00 does not.